# Handle javascript in selenium ide

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, selenium, selenium-ide

Below is the example where i failed post clicking of submit button:

```
package demo;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class leadtest 
        {
    private Selenium selenium;
    private SeleniumServer server;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception 
                {
        server = new SeleniumServer();
        server.start();
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox",
            "http://www.careerfundas.com/");
        selenium.start();
            }

    @Test
   public void testLeadtest() throws Exception
                {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.click("id=wrapper");
        selenium.click("css=a.active-home > span");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=wrapper");
        selenium.click("css=li");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=confused_name");
        selenium.type("id=confused_name", "Shalini test");
        selenium.type("id=confused_email", "Shalinitest@test.com");
        selenium.type("id=confused_phoneno", "9090909090");
        selenium.select("id=conf_course", "label=Shipping and Logistics");
        selenium.click("link=Ask Expert");
        assertEquals(
            "Thank You ! Someone from Career Fundas experts panel will    contact you shortly.", selenium.getAlert());


            }



    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception 
       {
        selenium.stop();
   }

      }
```

Note:
Below is the error i am getting when i tried to run above java script.

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: There were no alerts
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.
throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError (HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)
```

Comment: May be, the alert is not displayed by the time server is executing `getAlert()` command. Try adding `selenium.waitforpagetoload(30000);`
before assertion statement and check the behaviour. If still you are facing issue. let us know.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may try setting the speed by `selenium.setSpeed("5000")` before you
   do a `geralert`.
2. Maybe it is not alert. Maybe it is confirmation.
   Did you try `selenium.getConfirmation();`

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/oLb9xO3mD_I/47-OXDJ0BjcJ) is some More information on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
selenium.click("link=Ask Expert");
Thread.sleep(5000);
assertEquals("Thank You ! Someone from Career Fundas experts panel will contact you shortly.", selenium.getAlert());
```

Use this code, its working at my end